# What is the purpose of base_footprint?

Tags: ros, gazebo, urdf, base-footprint

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What purpose does the base_footprint link serve?

I'm reading through the [Gazebo simulation tutorial](http://www.romin.upm.es/wiki/index.php?title=ROS%3ATutorials/Simulate_Your_Robot_in_Gazebo), and it instructs the user to create an infinitesimally small nearly weightless box which is linked to the base_link, but it doesn't explain what this is or what it's used for, nor does it link to any resources that do. I did see this [similar question](http://answers.ros.org/question/12770/base_link-to-base_footprint-transform/), but that answer doesn't really explain *why* such a link is used. Why does any part of ROS need to know how the model projects onto the ground?

Does every Gazebo model require this link?

Edit: I've noticed the joint linking the footprint to the base_link has an origin whose z component represents a fixed distance from the ground. What value do you use for a legged model that doesn't have a fixed distance from the ground?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208051/what-is-the-purpose-of-base_footprint?/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2015-04-27

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In addition to some empirical answers, there's a [REP-120](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0120.html#base-footprint) that defines `base_footprint` link.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe it is to be viewed as a stable  projection  onto the ground plane(z=0)  used  for object avoidance and such.Not sure if it needs to be limited to the base link in terms of size of  the projection in this since it could treat like a bounding box that it is attached as a child link of the base link.

Ans: updated based on comments.

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) with karma: 713 on 2015-04-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2015-04-29**:
All the examples are for wheeled platforms and so used a fixed z for the base_footprint joint. What do you use for a legged model whose distance from the ground constantly varies?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-04-29**:
base_footprint should always be at z 0. The thing that varies in that case is the transform base_footprint -> base_link.

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2015-04-29**:
In the tutorial link I posted, the example uses a non-zero value for z in the base_footprint_joint origin.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2015-05-01**:
Since `base_footprint_joint` seems to be a joint, not a link, it can have non-zero z value.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

footprint allows  your robot to avoid the obstacles ,  base_footprint should  be  used for transform the  base_footprint coordinates to  robot base and calculation the  distance between  your robot base  and obstacle .  for Simulation realty and auto  calculating , that should  use , I guess ..

---

Originally posted by [Atilay Mayadag](https://answers.ros.org/users/22277/atilay-mayadag/) with karma: 13 on 2015-04-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1